# How to restrict inputting text only for a specified time in Tkinter Text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, time, text-widget

I am trying to implement a text widget in `tkinter` which will allow input text for only a specified time (here 5 secs) and then capture the typed text, without using a submit button calling a function.

I want the time to start as soon as user starts typing and shall prevent user inputting any longer after 5secs. The text that was inputted thus far shall be catured.

I tried the below code which is not working. I tried looking in the documentation and did web search and many `stackoverflow` discussion threads. I couldn't find an answer. Appreciate inputs on a solution.

```
from tkinter import *

my_window = Tk()
type_txt = Text()
type_txt.grid(row=0, column=0)
type_txt.focus()
type_txt.after(5000, type_txt.configure(state=DISABLED))
typed_text = type_txt.get("1.0", END)

print(typed_text)

my_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `<key>` event to a function, then inside the callback to disable the text box 5 seconds later using `.after()`.

```py
from tkinter import *

my_window = Tk()

type_txt = Text()
type_txt.grid(row=0, column=0)
type_txt.focus()

def disable_textbox():
    type_txt.configure(state=DISABLED)
    typed_text = type_txt.get("1.0", END)
    print(typed_text)

def start_typing(event):
    # disable <Key> binding
    type_txt.unbind('<Key>')
    # disable text box 5 seconds later
    type_txt.after(5000, disable_textbox)

type_txt.bind('<Key>', start_typing)
my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. While I could solve the disable portion of the problem, I could not figure how to enable the start. Thanks for the help. I have noticed a curious issue. If I change the function name from 'disable_textbox' to 'results' (including calling it in start_typing function), I am getting an error. But, if I change the function name to display_results, it works fine. Is there an issue naming a function as results?

Comment: Did you have another thing using the variable name `results`?  I don't think there is issue on naming a function as `results`.

Comment: I have a Label name 'Results". I don't think it should cause the problem.

Comment: Yes it will override the function.

Comment: Oh... So the case (lower and Capital cases) does not matter... Anyhow, thanks. I will recheck.

Comment: I missed the capital R.  If it is `Results` for the label and `results` is the function, then it should be OK.